# Image Animation on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've created a listbox with two images

```
<ListBox x:Name="list1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,10,0,-10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </ListBox.RenderTransform>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <Image Source="{Binding image}"  Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

How can I now have a forever animation alternating between the two images... if there's any easier way please tell. I want something easy [e.g. show image A for 5 seconds then shows image B for 5 seconds... then restart]

Comment: Is your code sample complete? You're only showing one image and nothing about how you're trying to change them.

Comment: My code sample isn't complete but I'm lost... I don't know what to do... I read about storyboard and I couldn't figure out how to push the image up so that the next image would show in its place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple with the StoryBoard concept as you said. First add two images inside your grid like this,

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid Margin="0,24,0,24">
            <Image Name="image1" Source="/Assets/1.jpg" />
            <Image Name="image2" Source="/Assets/2.jpg" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Then add the following code above your main Grid in your page. It should be in PhoneApplicationPage.Resources like this,

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="0"/>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Finally add the following code in OnNavigatedTo in your .cs file.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard1.Begin();
    }
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="Imag1" ImageSource="Assets/Logo.png"></ImageBrush>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="Imag2" ImageSource="Assets/Cera.png"></ImageBrush>
</Page.Resources>


<Grid Height="200" Width="200" Background="{StaticResource Imag1}" Name="Gd">
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:2"  RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="Gd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{StaticResource Imag2}" ></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```